# Explicit Kummer isomorphism

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a characteristic $0$ field containing $\mu_n$ (the $n$-th roots of unity). Then it known that the map $K^{\times} / (K^{\times})^n \to \mathrm{Hom}(G, \mu_n)$ which sends $x$ to $\sigma \mapsto \frac{\sigma(x^{1/n})}{x^{1/n}}$ is well defined and is an isomorphism (here $G$ denotes the absolute Galois group of $K$).

Is it possible to give an explicit description of the inverse of this map ?

Comment: Good question. Usually bijectivity is proven from degree consierations. I don't think that there is a description which is more explicit than "Given $h : G \to \mu_n$, there is some $y \in K^*$ such that $h(\sigma) y = \sigma(y)$, then $y^n$ is a preimage.". And probably there are a lot more abstract descriptions, for example I think this is induced by a long exact sequence of cohomology groups.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $\chi\in\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mu_n)$. Let $H$ be the kernel of $G$ and let $L$ be the fixed field of $H$. For $\alpha\in L$, let
$$
x(\alpha)=\sum_{\tau\in G/H} \chi^{-1}(\tau)\tau(\alpha).
$$
Notice that
$$
\sigma(x(\alpha))=\sum_{\tau\in G}\chi^{-1}(\tau)\sigma\tau(\alpha)=\sum_{\tau\in G}\chi(\sigma)\chi^{-1}(\tau)\tau(\alpha)=\chi(\sigma)x(\alpha).
$$
So if $x(\alpha)$ is non-zero, you have constructed an element that transforms by $\chi$.
Linear independence of characters tells you that there are lots of $\alpha$ that do this.

Comment: $G$ is infinite, so how to make sense of the sum? Also, $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$ for $\tau \in G$, $\alpha \in K^*$.

Comment: I fixed my answer but it may not be very satisfying.  It depends a little bit on what "explicit" means.  How do you "explicitly" give a character of $G$?  Thanks -